# How to create an object model from a database in dot net? invalid object name 'MyData'

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I need to connect to a database using EntityCoreFrameWork, but I am getting the error: `Invalid object name 'MyData'`. I'm guessing my object model is not correct or not connecting to right table.

To solve I think I can use a correct object model, so is there a way to auto generate the model? Like we can with VSStudio server explorer - show table data.

My table name is _tbl_Temp, my object name is MyData.
Code:

```
public class MyData
{
    [Key]
    public long COL123 { get; set; }
    public long SID { get; set; }
    public decimal cLen { get; set; }
    public decimal cWid { get; set; } 
    public byte[] Rowversion_1725301256 { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyData> MyData { get; set; }
}

app.MapGet("/pizza", async ([FromServices] MyDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    try
    {

        var allData = await dbContext.MyData.ToListAsync();
        return "Ok";

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }

    /* var allData = await dbContext.MyData.ToListAsync();
     return new JsonResult(allData);*/


});
```

tested after removing 'Rowversion_1725301256', same error.

and table definition screenshot:
[image]

Comment: "I am getting the error" - at compile time? If so, on which line... or is it an exception, in which case please provide the stack trace? It would also be clearer if you could show the table definition as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Its not at compile time. I'm getting error while hitting the endpoint '/pizza', on catch block it returns exception message.

Comment: Where is the code that maps your class, `MyData` to the (oddly name permanent) table `_tbl_temp`?

Comment: Well I would *start* by removing that catch block - let the exception propagate, and you can see the full stack trace instead of just the message. (Losing exception detalis like this is almost always unhelpful...) Then put the complete exception details in the question.

Comment: Thank you @ThomA , I forgot to map the tables to object. I got the solution, after mapping to object it is working.